# JQuery JSON replace character in a loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm creating a website and needed some help with this JSON file. 
I've managed to get it to display on the webpage and need to replace certain characters with images. I'm new to web programming and would appreciate a few tips.

This is my JQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'hall.json',dataType:'json',
  success: function(d) {
    for (var i=0;i<d.seats.length;i++){
    vr = "</br>"
        $('.layout').append(d.seats[i] + vr);}
    }
});
```

The code in the JSON file is as follows:

```
{"seats":["00000000000000000011111111111111000000000000000000","0000000000000001111111111111111aaa0000000000000000","00000000000000aa111111111111111aaaaa00000000000000","00000000000001111111111111111111111111000000000000","000000000aa00aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1100aa000000000","00000001111001111111111111111111111100111100000000","00000aaaaaa0011aaaaaaaaa11111111aaa1100aaaaaa00000","00001111111001111111111111111111111100111111100000","000aaaaaaa110011111111111111111111110011aaaaaaa000","00111111111100111111111111111111111001111111111000","00aaaaa1111110011111111111111111111001111aaaaaaa00","11111111111100111111111111111111111001111111111110","0aaaaaaaaaaaa001111111111111111111100aaaaaaaaaaaa0","01111111111110011111111111111111110011111111111100","00000000000000001111111111111111110000000000000000","01111111111111001111111111111111100111111111111100","01111111111111001111111111111111110011111111111110","01111111111111001111111111111111100111111111111100","00a11111111111100111111111111111100111111111111a00","00111111111111100111111111111111001111111111111000","00011111111111110011111111111111001111111111111000","00111111111111100111111111111111001111111111111000","00011111111111110011111111111111001111111111111000","00011111111111110011111111111110011111111111110000","0000000111a111111001111a1111a110011111111110000000","00000000111111110011111111111110011111111000000000","00000000001111111001111111111110011111110000000000","00000000000000111001111111111100111000000000000000"],"rows":["DD","CC","BB","AA","Z","Y","W","V","U","T","S","R","Q","P","N","M","L","K","J","H","G","F","E","DC","B","A"],"seatPrice":["                  00000000000000                  ","               0000000000000000000                ","              0000000000000000000000              ","             0000000000000000000000000            ","         00  000000000000000000000000  00         ","       0000  00000000000000000000000  0000        ","     000000  000000000000000000000000  000000     ","    0000000  00000000000000000000000  0000000     ","   000000000  0000000000000000000000  000000000   ","  0000000000  000000000000000000000  0000000000   ","  00000000000  00000000000000000000  00000000000  ","000000000000  000000000000000000000  000000000000 "," 000000000000  00000000000000000000  000000000000 "," 000000000000  0000000000000000000  000000000000  ","                000000000000000000                "," 0000000000000  00000000000000000  0000000000000  "," 0000000000000  000000000000000000  0000000000000 "," 0000000000000  00000000000000000  0000000000000  ","  0000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000  ","  0000000000000  000000000000000  0000000000000   ","   0000000000000  00000000000000  0000000000000   ","  0000000000000  000000000000000  0000000000000   ","   0000000000000  00000000000000  0000000000000   ","   0000000000000  0011111111100  0000000000000    ","       0000000000  111111111111  0000000000       ","        00000000  1111111111111  00000000         ","          0000000  111111111111  0000000          ","              000  00000000000  000               "],"priceLookup":[10,20]}
```

I am trying to replace "0" with a specific image and the same for "1" and "a"
Also I'm not sure if I have done it correctly but to replace the commas with a new line I used the `<br>` tag. Is that the correct thing to do?

Comment: I don't see the code that is trying to replace o,1,a with images. You are correctly inserting a line break in between each element in your array (the commas). Your question should always say "my program should be doing A but it's doing B". What is the actual problem with your code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4RkLc/

Answer (score 2):

If your code is working and the only thing you need is to replace the text with images you can do the following

```
$.ajax({
  url:'hall.json',
  dataType:'json',
  success: function(d) {
    var html = "";
    for (var i=0;i<d.seats.length;i++){
        var seat = d.seats[i];
        // Could use a single replace instead of three different calls but I
        // don't know what you need for each image, so optimization's up to you
        seat = seat.replace(/1/g, "<img src='1.png' />");
        seat = seat.replace(/a/g, "<img src='a.png' />");
        seat = seat.replace(/0/g, "<img src='0.png' />");
        html += seat + "< br />";
    }
    $('.layout').append(html);}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$.getJSON('hall.json', function(data) {
    var $layout = $('.layout');  // Cache it
    var seats = data.seats;

    for (var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
        var seat = seats[i];

        for (var j = 0; j < seat.length; j++) {
            var char = seat.charAt(j);

            $('<img />', {
                src: 'images/' + char + '.png',
                alt: char
            }).appendTo($layout);
        }

        $layout.append('<br />');
    }
});
```

This'll replace `X` with `<img src="images/X.png" alt="X" />`.

Answer (score 0):

You should treat every single JSON element as an Array and you are not replacing `,` with `<br>` you are adding it each loop

```
$.ajax({
 url:'hall.json',dataType:'json',
 success: function(d) {
  for (var i=0;i<d.seats.length;i++){
vr = "</br>";

var currentLength  = d.seats[i].length; 
for(var j = 0; j < currentLength; j++) 
{
       if(d.seats[i][j] == '0')
       // do something 
       else 
       // do something else
}

        $('.layout').append(d.seats[i] + vr);}
    }
});
```

You should read more about JSON , arrays & JavaScript

I hope this can help :)